# Можно ли эти команды уложить в небольшой цикл?

Tags: python

```
    b1_1=brick()
    b1_1.create()
    b1_2=brick()
    b1_2.create()
    b1_3=brick()
    b1_3.create()
    b1_4=brick()
    b1_4.create()
    b1_5=brick()
    b1_5.create()
    b1_6=brick()
    b1_6.create()
    b1_7=brick()
    b1_7.create()
    b1_8=brick()
    b1_8.create()
    b1_9=brick()
    b1_9.create()
    b1_10=brick()
    b1_10.create()
    b1_11=brick()
    b1_11.create()
    b1_12=brick()
    b1_12.create()
    b1_13=brick()
    b1_13.create()
```

Здесь я создаю блоки для игры по типу пинг понга, так вот можно ли уложить эти команды в цикл? Если можно, то добавьте пожалуйста bricks.append(x), где x - блок

Comment: Я конечно не знаю остальных условий, но почему бы вам не переметить вызов (или весь код) метода `create()` в конструктор класса `brick`? А потом просто `bricks = [brick() for i in range(countOfBricks)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если в методе `create` сделать

```
return self
```

то можно вообще сделать так:

```
bricks = [brick().create() for _ in range(13)]
```

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте так:

```
bricks = []

for i in range(13):
    b = brick()
    b.create()
    
    bricks.append(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bricks = []
for i in range(1, 14):
    exec(f'b1_{i} = Brick(); b1_{i}.create(); bricks.append(b1_{i})')
```